# How to get list of items by using Task<List<T>> definition for task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I working with this code and getting error "method  "doSomthing1" does not exist in current context":

```
static void Main( ) {
  Stopwatch stopwatch1;
  stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch( );
  stopwatch1.Reset( );
  stopwatch1.Start( );
  Task<List<int>> myTask = Task<List<int>>.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => doSomething1( ) );
  //Task<int> myTask = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew( ( ) => doSomething2 () );

  Thread.Sleep( 500 );
  Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch( );
  stopwatch2.Reset( );
  stopwatch2.Start( );
  //myTask.Wait( );
  if( myTask.IsCompleted ) {
    stopwatch2.Stop( );
  }

   myTask.Result.ForEach (x => Console.WriteLine (x.ToString () ));
  stopwatch1.Stop( );
  Console.WriteLine( "Stopwatch 1 elapsed time " + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString( ) );
  Console.WriteLine( "Stopwatch 2 elapsed time " + stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString( ) );
  Console.Read( );
}

static List<int> doSomething1(  ) {
  Thread.Sleep( 2000 );
  return new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };     
}

static int doSomething2 () {
  Thread.Sleep( 2000 );
  int k = 2 ;
  return k ;
}
```

If I use the task with Task definition then every thing works but when I tried to use `Task<List<T>>` then I get error.

Could anyone explain the cause of error. Thanks

Comment: static void that returns int?

Comment: Coudld anyone explain why down vote. thanks

Comment: I would like to remove this question, can anyone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case sensitive method names, doh!.